# Error instalacion MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

Estoy instalando el Stack MEAN (MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, NodeJS) en ubuntu 16.04 al instalar mongo me tira el siguiente error.. alguien a solucionado esto antes?

anexo screnshot

Gracias de antemano!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: versión de mongo? `$ mongo --version` y ubuntu 32 o 64 bits? (si bien 32bits no está soportado es posible instalarlo pero para ubuntu hay que hacer un poco de acrobacia)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba del siguiente modo:

```
 1. sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
 2. sudo mongod --repair
 3. sudo service mongod start
 4. sudo service mongod status
```

Va del modo siguiente, con rm se elimina el archivo mond.lock; después con el segundo paso se trata de reparar al demonio/servicio de mongo.

Se intenta reiniciar el servicio/demonio llamado mongod

Al final si el arranque es exitoso con el último y cuarto paso se verifica el status del servicio

> El archivo .lock es aquel que guarda la configuración de las versiones
>   de algunas dependencias que requiere mongodb para poder funcionar

---

Recuerda ejecutar el comando con `sudo` para que eleves los privilegios y accedas como **root**